# MySQL update records. Date column is reset

Tags: mysql, sql, date

In the below SQL `my_date` is reset to the current time (time when update was executed).

I expected though that `my_date` column would stay untouched.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
create table abc (
  id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  my_date timestamp(6)
);

insert into abc(my_date) values (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR);
insert into abc(my_date) values (NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR);
insert into abc(my_date) values (NOW() + INTERVAL 22 HOUR);

select * from abc;

1   2017-09-21 06:09:59.0
2   2017-09-22 06:09:59.0
3   2017-09-22 16:09:59.0

alter table abc add external_id varchar(30);
update abc set external_id = id;

select * from abc;

1   2017-09-21 18:10:46.000742744   1
2   2017-09-21 18:10:46.000742744   2
3   2017-09-21 18:10:46.000742744   3
```

Comment: Reproducible: http://rextester.com/OAUW27820  SOLUTION: timestamp updates when record updates. use datetime and you don't have that issue.  [DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) An auto-updated column is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value.  if you dont' want this behavior use datetime instead of timestamp.

Comment: No, no triggers, no procedures, no other constraints. I have only that what is posted above.

Comment: May because your are using NOW() and now is a function gave you the date in live time and you did a request UPDATE and is normal.

Comment: Woow, but that is really strange. I need timestamp(6) for milliseconds.

Comment: `update abc set external_id = id, my_date = my_date;` **[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/NHPX6303)**

Comment: If the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable is disabled, the first TIMESTAMP column has both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if neither is specified explicitly. To suppress automatic properties for the first TIMESTAMP column, use one of these strategies:  (See docs)  `my_date datetime(6) DEFAULT 0` on table definition.

Comment: Cool! That helped. I'm relly confused about the thing that the first TIMESTAMP becomes DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP...But such MySQL world. Thank you both!

Comment: It's because you have a system variable disabled which causes it to behave that way.  change it or change the default on the table create.  I really like your example it truly was a MCVE  all questions should do this so the problem is easily understood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Enable the system variable: `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`
2. Set a default for the timestamp

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/edit/OAUW27820) setting a default

Define the table this way (add default 0)  demo shows behavior w/ o default and w/ default.)

```
create table SO46348743_abc (
  id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  my_date timestamp(6)  DEFAULT 0
);
```

The default 0 forces the system to only update the my_date value if a new value is presented and not on updates/inserts to other columns.

Directly from [DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns have no automatic properties unless they are specified explicitly, with this exception: If the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable is disabled, the first TIMESTAMP column has both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if neither is specified explicitly. To suppress automatic properties for the first TIMESTAMP column, use one of these strategies:

> Enable the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable. In this case, the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses that specify automatic initialization and updating are available, but are not assigned to any TIMESTAMP column unless explicitly included in the column definition.

Alternatively, if explicit_defaults_for_timestamp is disabled, do either of the following:

> Define the column with a DEFAULT clause that specifies a constant default value.

Specify the NULL attribute. This also causes the column to permit NULL values, which means that you cannot assign the current timestamp by setting the column to NULL. Assigning NULL sets the column to NULL, not the current timestamp. To assign the current timestamp, set the column to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or a synonym such as NOW().

Consider these table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0,
  ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE t2 (
  ts1 TIMESTAMP NULL,
  ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE t3 (
  ts1 TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT 0,
  ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```